# How to format Facebook chat in a novel?

Tags: formatting

When I write a chat dialogue in a novel, how should I format it? Since it is not direct speech, it obviously needs no quotation marks, but should I use italics, repeat the names, or how else is chat dialogue conventionally marked up in fiction?

---

**Examples**

Quotation marks look too much like face-to-face or telephone communication:

> Then she flipped back over to the Facebook page and sent him a friend request from Facebook.
>
> Judith: "Okay Terrance, I have you all dialed in now. You seem legit. What kind of photo shoots you want to do? Bikini or business suit?"
>
> Terrance: "Nah, strictly professional. Kind of like stock photo shooting. I just want to get some head shots of you, and talk about some other things that we can do in the local market. I don't want to come off as a player."

No markup looks like a typesetting mistake:

> Then she flipped back over to the Facebook page and sent him a friend request from Facebook.
>
> Judith: Okay Terrance, I have you all dialed in now. You seem legit. What kind of photo shoots you want to do? Bikini or business suit?
>
> Terrance: Nah, strictly professional. Kind of like stock photo shooting. I just want to get some head shots of you, and talk about some other things that we can do in the local market. I don't want to come off as a player.

Italics look awkward somehow:

> Then she flipped back over to the Facebook page and sent him a friend request from Facebook.
>
> Judith: *Okay Terrance, I have you all dialed in now. You seem legit. What kind of photo shoots you want to do? Bikini or business suit?*
>
> Terrance: *Nah, strictly professional. Kind of like stock photo shooting. I just want to get some head shots of you, and talk about some other things that we can do in the local market. I don't want to come off as a player.*

So how is this done?

Comment: I think what he's asking is how to format chat scripts when writing in a novel. Like two characters talking online. But that's just what I think...

Comment: @Monica I edited the question to make it on topic. Even if it is maybe not what the OP wanted (though, like Amin, I suspect it is), it is now a valuable and worthwhile question for us.

Answer (score 3):

You have several different options here, depending on what effect you're trying to achieve.

Chat room dialogue is a little tough to work with, because it's pure dialogue, with no emotion or action or simple visibility. Oftentimes, it's enough to say something like,

> "Roy chatted with Samantha. 'OMG my mom's addicted to FOX news like you wouldn't *believe*," Samantha wrote, and Roy grinned - that was Sam's mom to a T.

-- where you aren't recreating an entire conversation; you're just summing up the highlights, and you're focusing on one Point of View - here, Roy's - and showing the experience from his side.

If you do want to recreate chat at any length, what I've seen done a lot is custom formatting. If you choose a special font, and indent the text, it feels like a chat log that's "inserted" into the main text, like this:

[image: Chat excerpts within text]

(Full-size image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akHDw.jpg). Source: ["Incarnate," Scott Ciencin](https://web.archive.org/web/19970810122530/http://www.randomhouse.com/lurkerfiles/incarnate/printeincarnate5.html) )

It doesn't have to be this specific font, and style choice. This is rather dated, from when chat rooms were a lot less sophisticated - and monospace courier gave a "computer-y" feel that seemed appropriate to chat rooms; now you'll hardly see Courier New on the web anywhere. But the association is still there, so you could use this same style, or  - just pick a different distinct font, that gives the feeling you're going for.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use images? Take screen shots of an actual Facebook convo. I don't feel like this should be too terribly difficult. . .

Comment: If we are writing fiction – and making up the conversation in chat – how are we supposed to take a screenshot?

Comment: Dealing with images also makes a text much harder to work with and lay out, then simple styled text.